# Wordpress odd/even Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to utilize wordpress's odd/even feature to change content positions in a slide element depending on if it is "odd" or "even", kind of like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9uSp.png) it flips for each slide, granted, this isn't wordpress just yet but it is a functioning example. View-able at http://165.227.182.166/
Can someone help me figure this out with the PHP below! Thank you!

```
 <?php
   $slides = array();
   $counter = 0;
   $args = array('category_name' => 'slider', 'nopaging' => true, 'post_per_page'=> 5 );
   $query = new WP_Query($args);
   if($query->have_posts()):while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
   $counter++;
   $temp = array();
   $temp['image'] = the_post_thumbnail_url();
   $temp['content'] = the_field('content');
   $temp['title'] = get_the_title();
   $temp['excerpt'] = the_field('excerpt');
   $slides[] = $temp;
 ?>

 <?php if(count($slides) > 0) { ?>

 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

     <?php $i=0; foreach($slides as $slide) { extract($slide); ?>
      <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
       <!-- <?php if($counter % 2== 0):?> -->

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="<?php $image; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2><?php $title; ?></h2>
        <h4><?php $excerpt; ?></h4>
        <p>
          <?php $content; ?>
        </p>
      </div>

    <?php else:?>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2><?php $title; ?></h2>
        <h4><?php $excerpt; ?></h4>
        <p>
          <?php $content; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="<?php $image; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>

     <?php endif;?>
  </div>
  <?php $i++; }} ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_postdata();?>
 ?>
```

It looks like it should function(to me) but it doesn't and I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with css, just make one foreach. Like this:

```
<?php if(count($slides) > 0) { ?>

 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

     <?php $i=0; foreach($slides as $slide) { extract($slide); ?>
      <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
       <!-- <?php if($counter % 2== 0):?> -->

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="<?php $image; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2><?php $title; ?></h2>
        <h4><?php $excerpt; ?></h4>
        <p>
          <?php $content; ?>
        </p>
      </div>

     <?php endif;?>
```

And the css will be sometime like this:

```css
.item{
  display:flex;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) .col-md-6{
  order:0;
}

.item:nth-child(even) .col-md-6:first-child{
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carouselclass">
  <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Titulo</h2>
        <h4>Excerpt</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Titulo</h2>
        <h4>Excerpt</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Titulo</h2>
        <h4>Excerpt</h4>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, I was ill, this worked great for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: I got it working with your css and some other things, if you'd like to take a look, its in the development site here https://www.spencerk.xyz/
It's transitions are a little eh but functionality is there. Thank you for the help! I truly appreciate it!